# Weird shading when adding inset to smoothed beveled object

Tags: modeling, bevel, artifacts, smooth

I'm modeling this truck and when I try to inset to make the side windows there is this weird shading/square in the size of the inset and the edges stay the same when trying to extrude too.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Bevel Modifier* change *Limit Method* to *Weight* and tick *Harden Normals*. It also helps to increase the *Segments* field to 3 or 4. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and and select all the edges you want to bevel. Then press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring out the side bar. Adjust the value for  *Bevel Weight* under *Edge Data* for anything between 0.5 to 1.0 you prefer. This will turn the edges to a blue color depending on the intensity.

[image]

Then <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode* and right click select *Shade Auto Smooth*

[image]